# Change width of image in Opencv using Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I'm making a Python file that will make a filter to have color on the Canny filter in OpenCV. I do this change from grayscale to color using the code provided below. My problem is when I apply the concatenate method (to add the color back as Canny filter is converted to grayscale), it cuts the width of the screen in 3 as I show in the 2 screenshots of before the color is added and after. The code snippet shown is only the transformation from grayscale to colored images.

What I've tried:

1. Tried using NumPy.tile: this wasn't the wisest attempt as it just repeated the same 1/3 of the screen twice more and didn't expand it to take up the whole screen as I had hoped.
2. Tried changing the image to only be from the index of 1/3 of the screen to cover the entire screen.
3. Tried setting the column index that is blank to equal None.

[Image without the color added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEI7r.png)

[Image with the color added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI1bS.png)

My code:

```
def convert_pixels(image, color):
rows, cols = image.shape
concat = np.zeros(image.shape)
image = np.concatenate((image, concat), axis=1)
image = np.concatenate((image, concat), axis=1)
image = image.reshape(rows, cols, 3)

index = image.nonzero()
#TODO: turn color into constantly changing color wheel or shifting colors
for i in zip(index[0], index[1], index[2]):
    color.next_color()
    image[i[0]][i[1]] = color.color

#TODO: fix this issue below:
#image[:, int(cols/3):cols] = None # turns right side (gliched) into None type
return image, color
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you're using `concatenate` on the wrong axis. `axis=1` is the "columns" axis, so you're just putting two copies of zeros *next to* each other in the `x` direction. Since you want a three-channel image I would just initialize `color_image` with three channels and leave the original grayscale image alone:

```
def convert_pixels(image,color):
    rows, cols = image.shape
    color_image = np.zeros((rows,cols,3),dtype=np.uint8)

    idx = image.nonzero()
    for i in zip(*idx):
        color_image[i] = color.color

    return color_image,color
```

I've changed the indexing to match. I can't check this exactly since I don't know what your `color` object is, but I can confirm this works in terms of correctly shaping and indexing the new image.